# Bitcoin Core: estimated time to synced, without GUI

Tags: bitcoin-core, synchronization

I enjoy how the Qt program reports how much time remains to complete the chain synchronization, but I don't know how to get that without using the GUI.

Can you configure bitcoind to report that? Can you use bitcoin-cli to query that?